# SoapUI multi-node match assertion

Tags: xml, soapui

I have the following structure in response

[image: response]

I need an assertion that would check that for the given Role a given Action is present.

I know how to check for specific node with exists(...), but how do I check for an action for the role? fe. Assert that REVOKE_ROLE, UPDATE_ROLE exist for myRole.

I tried to put both expression in the same assertion, but it seems SoapUI allows only one expression per assertion. If I put them in separate assertions it will match all actions I look for regardless of the role. Is this kind of check possible using the XPath Match or am I doing it wrong and I should use some other assertion?

Comment: was it a json or xml?

Comment: Would you mind providing usable sample response instead above one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966274/groovy-script-assert-on-key-value-pairs-in-soap-ui-xml-response coudl help. you can use groovy script and a map to store [Role] and [Action]

Comment: Please add xml in text instead of image.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this using XQuery Match

expression:

```
<Result>
{
for $x in //ns1:getUserA/RolePro/RoleProv/Role[ns4:Abbreviation="myRole"]
return data($x/../Prov/Provi/ns4:Abbreviation/text())
}
</Result>
```

expected result:

```
<Result>REVOKE_ROLE UPDATE_ROLE GRANT_ROLE</Result>
```